# Upgrading the V70's HU603 with iPhone support

Tags: volvo

I checked the [FAQ](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq) and it does really seem clear to me if I can ask this or not... so I give it a go anyways.

I have a Volvo V70N, 2002 "Jubileums modell" with the premium sound package. That include the HU603 stereo, which I would like to upgrade with an iPhone connection.

My questions, how do I do that? Do you know about any good tutorials that might help me, preferably photo-tutorials?
Also, which connector is best for connecting an iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was using GROM Audio (http://www.gromaudio.com/) and bought their iPhone package. Got it installed in 10 min or so, quite simple. However, sometimes I have to power on and off the radio a few times for the Grom audio box to understand it is connected.

Tutorials can be found on their website!